# Select specific elements of an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

How to select the N elements then ignore the next N ones and then select the next N ones and so on?

foe example of the array a = 1:100;

b = 1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach # 1**

```
a1 = reshape([a zeros(1,2*N - rem(numel(a),2*N))],N,[]);
out = reshape(a1(:,1:2:end),1,[]);
if rem(numel(a),2*N)<N
    out = out(1:N*floor(numel(a)/(2*N)) + rem(numel(a),2*N)); %//output
end
```

**Approach # 2**

```
a1 = vec2mat(a,N)'; %//'
out = reshape(a1(:,1:2:end,:),1,[]);
if rem(numel(a),2*N)<N
    out = out(1:N*floor(numel(a)/(2*N)) + rem(numel(a),2*N)); %//output
end
```

**Approach # 3**

```
mat1 = [true false];
mat2 = reshape(mat1(ones(N,1),:),[],1);
mat3 = reshape(mat2(:,ones(1,ceil(numel(a)/(2*N)))),[],1);
out = a(mat3(1:numel(a)));  %//output
```

Comment: Dear Divakar, thank you, i have to look it up to understand how it works, how about selecting from for example an array, anything, for example an array of odd numbers?

Comment: @user3482383 You just have to change `N` for that

Comment: @user3482383 For that `N` has to be `2`. Also, check out the edits, for comments to help you understand, at least for the method 2.

Comment: how about if i just want to have the m group of them? for example in the above example the first 3 ones, like  1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15 ?!

Comment: @user3482383 Number of groups as `m`? `count_Ngroups` is what is `m` then, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @Divakar hi, i asked this question three month ago, is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: @user3482383 Check out the edits. Even if all of these edited approaches fail to deliver your expected efficiency in terms of runtime, could you report back their performances?